# How can I checkout another changeset while keeping HEAD on the current changeset?

Tags: git

I am looking at my two most recent changesets:

```
$ git log --oneline
123798 most recent stuff
349873 earlier changes
...
```

Currently I am on the 'most recent stuff' changeset. What I want to do is have the HEAD pointer stay on this changeset, but have the files look as though I was on 'earlier changes'. Sort of the opposite of `git reset --soft`, where the HEAD pointer moves but the files don't change.

**Edit**

What I've found works is to do

```
$ git checkout 349873
$ git reset --soft 123798
$ git reset HEAD
```

so this describes what I *want* to happen. But I'm wondering if there is a more succinct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git update-ref HEAD <desired-SHA>
```

This won't touch your working copy.

Comment: Hm I think this does the opposite of what I want. I want to _only_ update my working copy -- while keeping my HEAD pointed where it is.

Comment: @RobertMartin, the trick is `git reset --hard 349873 && git update-ref HEAD 123798`. Reset will give you the files from the earlier commit and update-ref will update your HEAD to point to the most recent commit.

Comment: agree with @KL although I'd prefer checkout instead of reset hard

Comment: @CharlesB checking out an earlier commit will leave you in a detached HEAD state. And even `update-ref` doesn't fix it. So if you want to stay on the same branch you have to reset.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a shorter way to do this, but:

```
if current=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD); then
    git checkout $@
    git symbolic-ref HEAD $current
fi
```

does the trick as a shell script.  (This is certainly an unusual thing to do...)  You'll get the usual "detached HEAD" message from the checkout command, and a subsequent attempt to go back to whatever branch you started on will complain that you're already on it, even though you're not.

(The above assumes you're at the tip of some branch and want to remain there.  If you're already in `detached HEAD` state it will complain that there's no symbolic-ref.  Use `rev=$(git rev-parse HEAD)` instead to find what rev HEAD is, then use `git update-ref HEAD $rev` to get back there.)